# Rescaling a line of a line chart, it is deformed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have taken the trouble to put my problem, and I hope you can understand me.
In my real project I have 7 sensors connected, which return a response with this structure.

```
[{"id":"sensor1_ciclo1","sensor":1,"ciclo":"ciclo1","values":
 [
  {"voltaje":0,"corriente":11.175}
 ]
```

the `"sensor"` key represents the sensor number. I have 7 input radios to represent each sensor.the key "ciclo", is a property of the sensor. I can filter for this property. Although, in this case, all my data are using `"ciclo": "ciclo1"`. In the line chart I draw the points using the keys `"corriente"` and `"voltaje"`.

In my real project, I get the data according to a n amount of time, for this case I am simulating them with a `setInterval` of 3 seconds. I want to paint the data that corresponds to the selected sensor with an animation. if the sensor1 is selected, I only want to put the sensor1 data.

If I change sensor, I would like to see the data that has been accumulated, and this is the main function of my function `reloadPoints` the accumulated values are in `oDataSensores`. The `display` function is responsible for drawing the data, and if the limit is greater than 250 or -250 on the y-axis, the chart is rescaled.

look the gif please.

[image]

I do not know how to fix it. The really strangest thing is that if I comment this line,

```
 Array.prototype.push.apply(oDataSensores[data[i].id].content.values, data[i].values);
```

it apparently works. But I need to accumulate the values by sensor so I can not delete this line. How can I solve that?

To reproduce the error, wait 9 seconds, and when the third line in sensor1 is added and the chart is rescaled (>250), this problem occurs.

so is the process that I want to achieve when a new point is added

[image]

This is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1s25ZVEM0pWZPkVJGart?p=preview

```
{
  "sensor1_ciclo1":{ "contador":0, "sensor":1, "content":[] },
  "sensor1_ciclo2":{ "contador":0, "sensor":1, "content":[] },
  "sensor1_ciclo3":{ "contador":0, "sensor":1, "content":[] },
  "sensor2_ciclo1":{ "contador":0, "sensor":2, "content":[] },
  "sensor2_ciclo2":{ "contador":0, "sensor":2, "content":[] },
  "sensor2_ciclo3":{ "contador":0, "sensor":2, "content":[] },       
  "sensor3_ciclo1":{ "contador":0, "sensor":3, "content":[] },
  "sensor3_ciclo2":{ "contador":0, "sensor":3, "content":[] },
  "sensor3_ciclo3":{ "contador":0, "sensor":3, "content":[] },   
  "sensor4_ciclo1":{ "contador":0, "sensor":4, "content":[] },
  "sensor4_ciclo2":{ "contador":0, "sensor":4, "content":[] },
  "sensor4_ciclo3":{ "contador":0, "sensor":4, "content":[] },    
  "sensor5_ciclo1":{ "contador":0, "sensor":5, "content":[] },
  "sensor5_ciclo2":{ "contador":0, "sensor":5, "content":[] },
  "sensor5_ciclo3":{ "contador":0, "sensor":5, "content":[] },    
  "sensor6_ciclo1":{ "contador":0, "sensor":6, "content":[] },
  "sensor6_ciclo2":{ "contador":0, "sensor":6, "content":[] },
  "sensor6_ciclo3":{ "contador":0, "sensor":6, "content":[] },    
  "sensor7_ciclo1":{ "contador":0, "sensor":7, "content":[] },
  "sensor7_ciclo2":{ "contador":0, "sensor":7, "content":[] },
  "sensor7_ciclo3":{ "contador":0, "sensor":7,"content":[] }   
};
```

Comment: I don't see oDataSensores in the file

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi I update the link. excuse me!

Answer (score 1):

Changing how the array.push works looks to fix your issue

```
aVoltamograma.push(data[i])
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NZcV24gEDX1ommcYUDTd?p=preview

Comment: It is an honor for me that you have answered me. but I think my code now does not work well. every time a point is added, I want to paint that point but with an animation. when I change the sensor I want to generate an animation of the accumulated of all the points per sensor. With your change, my error is solved, but these animations and functionality no longer work. :(

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/3ov9jGKAv6VoBffQR2/giphy.gif  so is the operation that I want to achieve. (but I have the error that I comment on this question)

Comment: Sorry, I commented out the animation while testing the array.push. updated the plunkr now http://plnkr.co/edit/NZcV24gEDX1ommcYUDTd?p=preview

Comment: tom! you are amazing I knew you would not disappoint me. is almost perfect only a small detail, why when you change the sensor, you do not see the animation with all the points accumulated until that moment ?. what I want is that every time a point is added an animation is displayed. (that's fine in your code). but when changing sensor I would like to show the animation of the line with all the points accumulated until that moment in that sensor.